How does ColliderScript improve Bitcoin and what features does it enable?
What is Colliderscript in layman terms? How does it work and what new features does it bring to Bitcoin? Does it require a hardfork?

Co-author here. ColliderScript is a covenant construction for Bitcoin that works without needing a softfork. Functionally, sufficiently powerful covenants allow Bitcoin to maintain persistent logic and state on-chain, enabling "smart contract" functionality akin to Ethereum.
ColliderScript enables the same type of (powerful) covenants you would get from OP_CAT, a proposed opcode softfork mentioned in BIP347. This BIP also lists possible applications relevant to ColliderScript, including vaults and emulating CSFS.
I wrote an article on why OP_CAT (and consequently ColliderScript) also enables smart contracts and (Ethereum-style) rollups on Bitcoin:
https://starkware.co/blog/general-computation-on-bitcoin/
Nevertheless, unlike OP_CAT, ColliderScript is extremely computationally intensive. It answers in the affirmative the previously open question of whether covenants are possible on Bitcoin without a softfork.
Here is a good article on ColliderScript:
https://bitcoinmagazine.com/technical/colliderscript-a-50m-bitcoin-covenant-with-no-new-opcodes
